# Trouble with the headers of various c++ class in separate files

Tags: c++, oop

I have 5 files, a main file and two classes with its two headers files like that:

file main.cpp:

```
#include "parent.hpp"
#include <iostream>

int main (){
    Parent parentInstance;
    parentInstance.function();
    return 0;
}
```

file parent.hpp:

```
class Parent {
    public:
        void function();
};
```

file parent.cpp:

```
#include "child1.hpp"

 void Parent::function() {
    Child1 Child1Instance;
    Child1Instance.speak();
}
```

file child1.hpp:

```
#include "parent.hpp"
#include <iostream>

class Child1 : public Parent {
    public:
        void speak();
};
```

file child1.cpp:

```
#include "child1.hpp"

void Child1::speak () {
    std::cout << "Hi, I'm child1" << '\n';
    }
```

It compile and works without any problem, -although it may have been done with bad practices-. The problem rises when I try to add a new class with its own cpp and hpp files, called Child2 that its basically the same code than Child1, but I don't know how organize properly the headers for make this code works:

```
 void Parent::function() {
    Child1 Child1Instance;
    Child2 Child2Instance;
    Child1Instance.speak();
    Child2Instance.speak();
}
```

and return me:

```
Hi, I'm child1 
Hi, I'm child2
```

Comment: I don't see the purpose of the inheritance here. Remembering that inheritance is a "is-a" relationship, is e.g. `Child1` really a `Parent` as well? Perhaps you should have a *separate* "parent" class just for `Child1` and `Child2` (one that is different from the class `Parent` you show) which have a virtual abstract `speak` function declared?

Comment: Why can't you just include `child2.hpp` the same way you did with `child1.hpp`? What's the exact problem you are facing?

Comment: @Karsten-Koop, The error compiler are:
parent.hpp:2:7: error: redefinition of ‘class Parent’
parent.hpp:2:7: error: previous definition of ‘class Parent’

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thats the reason i dislike this child-parent analogy so much. To me it doesnt make any sense to say a child is-a parent when you inherit a "child" class from a "parent" class, it is completely misleading language

Comment: If `Parent::function()` is trying to instantiate instances of multiple classes the compiler needs visibility of the definition of all those class types.   That is achieved by including all the corresponding headers.    Also, since you will have `parent.h` included by multiple headers, it is necessary for it to have an include guard.

Comment: @user463035818 and Some programmer dude, thanks, now I understand the name's problem. I just chose those names in a hurry for this example, they are not the names of the real code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some rules:

1. A header file always has [include guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) (or [`#pragma once`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once)).
2. Every `.cpp` includes its corresponding `.hpp` as its first (non-comment) line.
3. Only include into a `.cpp` what you explicitly use in that `.cpp`.

This should solve most of your problems.

---

Some explanations:

1. Without the guards, you can end up including the same file twice transitively, say you include `a.h` and `b.h`, but `b.h` already includes `a.h`... This causes some confusing redefinition errors.
2. You must include the header so that function *definitions* in the `.cpp` correspond to the *declarations* in the `.hpp`. Having it on the very first line is just good practice.
3. Including exactly what you use avoids confusing errors if you forgot an `#include` somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I'm very grateful for the comments, all my knowledge is self-taught...now the problem is easily solved:

main.cpp has no change.

file parent.hpp:

```
#ifndef _PARENT_HPP_
#define _PARENT_HPP_

class Parent {
    public:
        void function();
};

#endif /* _PARENT_HPP_ */
```

file parent.cpp:

```
#include "parent.hpp"
#include "child1.hpp"
#include "child2.hpp"

 void Parent::function() {
    Child1 Child1Instance;
    Child2 Child2Instance;
    Child1Instance.speak();
    Child2Instance.speak();
}
```

file child1.hpp and child2.hpp (change 1 to 2):

```
#include "parent.hpp"
#include <iostream>

class Child1 : public Parent {
    public:
        void speak();
};
```

file child1.cpp and child2.cpp (change 1 to 2):

```
#include "child1.hpp"

void Child1::speak () {
    std::cout << "Hi, I'm child1" << '\n';
    }
```

And the result:

```
Hi, I'm child1
Hi, I'm child2
```

It works. However, I'd like to hear if there's anything that could be improved or a mistake that could be corrected.